# Minor details of Mermin-Wagner

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, phase-transition, crystals, spin-models

In the proof of Mermin-Wagner (e.g., [scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Mermin-Wagner_Theorem#Proof)), there is a minor assumption that the average magnetization $m_\Lambda (h)$ converges in the thermodynamic limit $\Lambda \to \mathbb{Z}^d$ to some $m(h)$ for all nonzero magnetic field $h$. Indeed, ignoring constants, what is rigorously proven is that
$$
\frac{1}{|\Lambda|}\sum_{k\in \Lambda^*} \frac{m_\Lambda^2}{k^2 + |h m_\Lambda|} \le  C
$$
If $m_\Lambda (h) \to m(h)$, I can apply Fatou's lemma (taking $\text{lim inf}$) so that we can have the continuoum
$$
\int_{k\in\text{BZ}} \frac{d^d k}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{m^2}{k^2 + |hm|} \le C
$$
And the rest follows as in the proof.

**Question**. Is there some reason why $m_\Lambda (h)$ converges? For example, in the classical case, there's the definition of the Gibbs state. Is there a quantum version of that?